# Retrieving data from viewmodel to fragment fails

Tags: android, kotlin, scope, viewmodel, coroutine

```
 viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, ActiveAssessmentViewModelViewModelFactory()).get(ActiveAssessmentViewModel::class.java)
```

this is de viewmodel creation in the oncreateview method in the fragment

```
  init {
    getQuestions()
}
/**
 *
 */
fun getQuestions() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        token = "bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.n526VEMkb19pFhZ_Hw-n04XwO8EYBP0pAan0I-Hy9t0"
        var wait = ApiServiceObject.retrofitService.getQuestionsForAssessment(token)
        var response = wait.result!!.items
        _questions.value = response

    }

}
```

this is the init and de get function of my questions

Comment: What you want to do is start looking at LiveData and setting up an observer for your data. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: What does "fails" actually mean? A crash or what?

Comment: The questions property of viewmodel in the fragment is empty